# Merging Two Matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I've done a little bit of digging for this result but most of the questions on here have information in regards to the cbind function, and basic matrix concatenation. What I'm looking to do is a little more complicated.

Let's say, for example, I have an NxM matrix whose first column is a unique identifier for each of the rows (and luckily in this instance is sorted by that identifier). For reasons which are inconsequential to this inquiry, I'm splitting the rows of this matrix into (n_i)xM matrices such that the sum of n_i = N.

I'm intending to run separate analysis on each of these sub-matrices and then combine the data together again with the usage of the unique identifier.

An example:
Let's say I have matrix `data` which is 10xM. After my split, I'll receive matrices subdata1 and subdata2. If you were to look at the contents of the matrices:

```
data[,1] = 1:10
subdata1[,1] = c(1,3,4,6,7)
subdata2[,1] = c(2,5,8,9,10)
```

I then manipulate the columns of `subdata1` and `subdata2`, but preserve the information in the first column. I would like to combine this matrices again such that `finaldata[,1] = 1:10`, where `finaldata` is a result of the combination.

I realize now that I could use `rbind` and the sort the matrix, but for large matrices that is very inefficient.

I know R has some great functions out there for data management, is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: This is a common operation known a "split-apply-combine". Of the numerous possibilities, package `plyr` offers probably the easiest syntax for a beginner.

Comment: Ask clearly and provide some reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand your question, but as an example of general use, I would typically convert the matrices to dataframes and then do something like this:

```
combi <- rbind(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

Comment: I'll make an edit to the question to clarify, but I can't do this because my identifying key will now be out of order.

Comment: Why do your IDs have to be in a specific order?  Could they be re-ordered afterward?

Comment: They could, but I'm dealing with a fairly large amount of data. That is the current method I'm employing, but I'm hoping for something more efficient

Answer (score 0):

If you know they are matrices, you can do this with multidimensional arrays:

```
X <- matrix(1:100, 10,10)
s1 <- X[seq(1, 9,2), ]
s2 <- X[seq(2,10,2), ]
XX <- array(NA, dim=c(2,5,10) )
XX[1, ,] <- s1 #Note two commas, as it's a 3D array
XX[2, ,] <- s2
dim(XX) <- c(10,10)
XX
```

This will copy each element of `s1` and `s2` into the appropriate slice of the array, then drop the extra dimension. There's a decent chance that `rbind` is actually faster, but this way you won't need to re-sort it.

Caveat: you need equal sized splits for this approach.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I'm going to have a large variety of split differences. That and they won't necessarily be alternating in the split, mat1 may have c(1,2,5,7,8,9,10) and mat2 c(3,4,6)